# Stow away [magazine]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [magazine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magazine) has no tag wiki and 30 random questions.  Could we please get rid of it?

To me, this looks like the *kittens* case from [the burnination process documentation in this meta answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191).

The majority of questions seem to be about newsstand-type apps.  For IOS, there is a dedicated tag for that; [newsstand-kit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/newsstand-kit).  I could not find anything similar for Android, although a few questions are about that, too.  There are also questions about many other problems that have aspects "like in a magazine" but I could not find anything properly generalizable which would still be useful as the meaning of a tag.

Comment: The linked question was voted `+27 / -8`, yet the tag wasn't burninated. We should have another shot at it.

Comment: Perhaps `Unsubscribe [magazine]`?

Comment: @Pekka웃 Yeah, that's better. I was looking for the secondary meaning of "ammunition storage" (which is the primary use in my language).

Comment: FYI - All [tag:magazine] questions are now closed.

Comment: @TylerH Wow, amazing!

Comment: There are now 16 new questions with this tag.

Comment: Has 2 closed questions at the moment.